# Converting a negative fraction to IEEE 754

Tags: ieee-754

I'm trying to convert -0.25 in decimal to IEEE 754 8-bit floating point. This means the signed bit is 1 bit, the exponent is 3 bits and the mantissa is 4 bits. Since it's a fraction my first digit is 0. For my next digits

```
.25 * 2 = **0**.5
.5 * 2 = **1**.0
0 * 2 = **0**.0...
```

So I end up with 0.01000. I then move the decimal two to the right so I end up with 1 * 2^-2 which is correct except aren't I supposed to subtract the bias of 3 to make it 1 * 2^-5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't aware that IEEE 754 defines an 8-bit format. (In fact I'm still not convinced it does.) But we can extrapolate from the formats it does define.

You don't mention a hidden bit, but the 16, 32, 64, and 128 bit IEEE 754 formats all use a hidden bit, so I'll solve this with a hidden bit.

I think it's simplest to describe the components of a floating point number as three separate unsigned integers. (I learned this trick from [this paper](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~dyb/pubs/FP-Printing-PLDI96.pdf).) For your 8-bit format, these integers are

- `s`, the sign bit, which is 0 or 1,
- `e`, the exponent, which has the range 0...7,
- `m`, the significand, which has the range 0...15.

The format uses a hidden bit, which we handle by adding 2<sup>4</sup>, also known as 16, to the significand. (The 4 here comes from the number of bits in the significand.)

You described the bias as 3, but since I'm treating the significand as an integer, I need to add 4 to the bias (to shift all but the hidden bit to the right of the radix point).  This makes the bias 7 in my notation.

Thus we define the value of a floating-point number `f` as

```
f = (-1)^s * 2^(e-7) * (m + 16)
```

Now let's solve your problem, which is to find `s`, `e`, and `m` given

```
f = -0.25
```

Substitute into the earlier definition of `f`:

```
-0.25 = (-1)^s * 2^(e-7) * (m + 16)
```

We can see immediately that `s == 1`. Divide out the -1 to give

```
0.25 = 2^(e-7) * (m + 16)         (eq. 1)
```

Solve this for `m + 16`:

```
m + 16 = 0.25 / 2^(e - 7)
       = 0.25 * 2^-(e - 7)
       = 0.25 * 2^(7 - e)
```

We know that `0 <= m < 16` (since `m` is 4 bits), so `16 <= m + 16 < 32`. Substitute and solve for non-negative integer e:

```
16 <= 0.25 * 2^(7 - e) < 32
64 <= 2^(7 - e) < 128
log2 64 <= 7 - e < log2 128
6 <= 7 - e < 7
-1 <= -e < 0
1 >= e > 0
e = 1
```

Now substitute `e = 1` back into equation 1 and solve for `m`:

```
0.25 = 2^(1 - 7) * (m + 16)
0.25 = 2^-6 * (m + 16)
16 = (m + 16)
m = 0
```

So `s = 1`, `e = 1`, and `m = 0`. Plug back into the definition of `f` to check:

```
f = (-1)^1 * 2^(1 - 7) * (0 + 16)
  = -1 * 2^-6 * 16
  = -1 * 1/64 * 16
  = -1/4
  = -0.25
```

To turn this into bits, we write out the one bit of of `s`, followed by the three bits of `e`, followed by the four bits of `m`:

```
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
s e e e m m m m
```

Thus 16 (base 10), or 0x10, is the binary representation of 0.25 as an 8-bit floating point number.

Comment: Thanks, 8-bit my prof just used as a theoretical example